# DustJS Filter For Double Quotes?

Tags: dust.js

Quick question. I'm receiving as input a JSON value with double quotes escaped with a backslash, I need to output them in html entities. Is there a filter that can achieve this? Thanks!

Input

```
{ foo: "60\"x50\"" }
```

Output

```
60&quot;x50&quot;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need a "|s" filter. Given data from your example `{foo|s}` will output `60"x50"`